# Showing correct value based on three lookup variables

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create a salary calculator in Excel formulas, however the instructions i have used to create a way to look up 3 variables is not working. I have looked at the methods in the link below but they all require the table format changing? is there a way to keep table as it is.

https://professor-excel.com/3d-lookups-excel/#Method_1_8220Cheating8221_by_changing_the_structure_of_your_data

The Wage per hour rate that I want to be returned depend on several variables (drop down menus).

1. Skill Set 2. Experience 3. Quality of Experience (ranked low medium high)

I have struggled for a while and tried different methods to work this out. I have attached a dummy document to this.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnQEPbEJrVkolBWmkIRA9bA7LmgD?e=IHzgKZ

Is there a way to do this without changing table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since I could preview the sheet without downloading:

```
=INDEX(C4:S32,MATCH(V4,B4:B32,0),IFERROR(MATCH(V5,C2:S2,0)+MATCH(V6,D3:F3,0)-1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have tried your forumla but what ever variables i put in just get the intern price (27.50), I have everything in the exact same location as the picture above.

Comment: the experience must match exactly what you have in row 3.  `(1-2)`,`(3-5)` etc. and the same with the quality.

Comment: Yes i have tried to use the drop down to values of the values in the column B, row 3 and row 4. Without any luck. Does it need to be an array forumla?

Comment: It works now might error! Thank you very much!